# AngularJS observing div size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onchange

I still learning how **AngularJS** works and I'm tackling how `$watch` works. I have this scenario that I wanted to watch the dimension of the `div.id="area"`. Since I'm watching the dimensions, I was planning to trigger a function upon any change of values (`clientWidth` and `clientHeight`).

So far what I've got so far, as per my understanding about `$watch` is this:

```
$scope.browser = {
    width: document.getElementById("area").offsetWidth,
    height: document.getElementById("area").offsetHeight
};
console.log($scope.browser);
$scope.$watch("browser", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("changed from: " + oldValue.width + " to " + newValue.width);
}, true);
```

Any ideas how I could get the watch working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's more similar to your requirement. Instead of the div the dimensions of the window is printed.

```
function Dimensions($scope){
    $scope.docWidth = 0;
    $scope.docHeight = 0;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kapilgopinath/ayVW6/

Comment: Click the dimensions button. Try to resize your browser to get the changed dimensions.

Comment: did you check the fiddle

Comment: Or maybe because it isn't showing the updated value of `doc.width` on HTML

Comment: try checking in chrome

Comment: It worked, I was wondering how it would worked without pressing the button.

Comment: It was an issue with document.height and width which wont work in some browsers

Comment: If it would work on Safari and Chrome it won't be an issue for me.

Comment: Actually there is no need of watch in your case as the scope variables docWidth and height are assigned new values. Only that we must assign values to height and width in some resize event.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I can't make it concrete since I'm new in **AngularJS**. Would there be a possibility to have the fiddle working  scenario I have?

Comment: The above link hope it matches your requirement

Comment: I have updated. This one is perfect match of ur case

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, you're watching immutable object. `width` and `height` are read once when `$scope.browser` is created. Because those values are never updated, `$watch` will never fire your callback.

There are several solutions:

1) You can watch function value instead of object value, e.g.:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return {
     width: document.getElementById("area").offsetWidth,
     height: document.getElementById("area").offsetHeight
   }
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
   console.log("changed from: " + oldValue.width + " to " + newValue.width);
}, true);
```

This is extremely inefficient (accessing DOM is slow), but possible, if other solutions are not possible to apply in your case.

2) Find situations in which `#area` changes it's dimensions. Is it browser resize? Is it jQuery/another 3d party script? For example, to intercept window resize, you can use such directive:

```
.directive('windowResize',['$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout){
  return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var fn = $parse($attrs.windowResize);
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        fn($scope);
      });
    });
}])

//template
<div id="area" window-resize="onWindowResize()"></div>
```

In case of another script, you could get scope from DOM send event or modify `$scope.browser` directly:

```
//jquery script
var dimensions = {widht: newWidht, height: newHeight};
updateAreaDimensions(dimensions);
//broadcast event, decoupling this script from scope's code
$('body').scope().$broadcast('areaDimensionsUpdated', dimensions);
//or modify your $scope.browser object
$('body').scope().browser = dimensions;
```

In case of event, you can listen to it in your scope:

```
$scope.$on('areaDimensionsUpdated', function($event, args) {
  //
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible if jQuery isn't included on the directive snippet you've provided?

Comment: Of course. jQuery here is only retrieving DOM elements and dispatching events. You can do that with pure JS as well, but you have to keep browser compatibility and quirks in mind. I'd leave those concerns to jQuery.

Comment: Would there be a conflict if `jQuery` and `angular` are used together?

Comment: No. In fact, angular uses jQuery, if it's included in the page. Otherwise, it uses its own jQuery implementation, called jqLite.

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
scope.browser = {
    width: document.getElementById("area").offsetWidth,
    height: document.getElementById("area").offsetHeight
};

$scope.$watch(function() {
    console.log("changed from: " + $scope.browser.width + " to " +  $scope.browser.width);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In addition, I think it's advisable to watch `$scope.browser` instead of watching the entire `$scope`.